# How would I display the winner in the following database schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have

```
 +----------+--------+-----------+
 |  RACE_ID |  NAME  | POSITION  |
 +----------+--------+-----------+
```

With primary key

```
 +----------+--------+
 |  RACE_ID |  NAME  |
 +----------+--------+
```

For a given competitor, I would like to display the name plus the winner of the race.  The winner of the race is whoever has POSITION=1 for the given RACE_ID.  So something like the following

```
SELECT NAME, (???) AS WINNER where NAME='Thorpe'
```

I'm not sure what goes in ???.  I'm using Postgres.

Comment: The condition `where name = 'Thorpe'` does not make sense because that assumes you already know who the winner is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think the OP is looking for any race that "Thorpe" ran in and wants to see the winner of that race.

Comment: @CapeCodGunny: interesting view on the problem. Let's wait for Hoa to make this clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming the table name is contestant, I'd try something like this below :

```
SELECT con.NAME, win.NAME AS WINNER
  from contestant con
  join contestant win
    on win.race_id = con.race_id
   and win.position = 1
 where con.NAME='Thorpe'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT R1.NAME AS WINNER
FROM RaceTable AS R1 
   INNER JOIN RaceTable AS R2 ON R1.RACE_ID = R2.RACE_ID
WHERE R2.NAME = 'Thorpe' AND R1.Position = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your example is clear.

I assumed that RaceID corresponds to the race, name is the name of the competitor, and position is their result for that race (this way the primary key makes sense, it means each name can only be in the same race once).

Assuming what I've said is correct, you've pretty much got all the components in your answer already. You haven't mentioned what the table is called, but it should go something a bit like this:

```
SELECT Name AS Winner
FROM table1
WHERE Position = 1
AND RaceID = ??
```

(As you said you you wanted it for a given RaceID)